# Using date input via Dateinput to be filename

Tags: date

I have a shiny UI which allows user to select a date via dateinput box. Given output from this will be backup daily hence would like to use such "date", eg 20181224 as part of filename.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- fluidPage(

sidebarPanel(

dateInput("COBInput", "Select a Date", value=Sys.Date())

))

server <- function(input,output,session){

COB <- reactive(as.Date(input$COBInput,format="%Y-%m-%d"))
COB2 <- paste(
"Test",as.character(
format(input$COBInput,format="%Y-%m-%d",'%Y')
)
)}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Error that I got :

> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4973
>   Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed
>   without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be
>   done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
>    54: stop
>    53: .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext
>    52: .subset2(x, "impl")$get
>    51: $.reactivevalues
>    47: server [N:/AdHoc Query/R/FFVA/DateInputTest/ShinyApp.R#42]
>   Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
>    Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

I would expect for each day, I could save file with name like "Daily20181224","Daily20181221" etc

Answer (score 0):

I was exactly not clear about the requirements but tried using textoutput which can give you idea about how to generate the filename.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarPanel(

    dateInput("COBInput", "Select a Date", value=Sys.Date()),
    textOutput("filename")

  ))

server <- function(input,output,session){

  output$filename<-renderText({
    input_date<-input$COBInput
    year <- as.numeric(format(input_date,'%Y'))
    month<-as.numeric(format(input_date,'%m'))
    day<-as.numeric(format(input_date,'%d'))
    paste0("Daily",year,month,day)
  })
} 
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I think you can generate the filenames now
One thing I like to say about ShinyFiles - I think you are aware that it can only be used for server side file browsing after deployment.